# Dynamics CRM Plugin - setting a related record

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I am writing a plugin which fires on the PostCreation of an invoice. This plugin creates a commission record and is supposed to set a lookup field on the commission record which points to the newly created invoice. However there seems to be no value for the Guid of the invoice while the plugin runs - I assume it only gets a Guid once it is committed to the database?

Is there a way in which I can get the Guid of the new invoice or even set it manually, so that I know what it will be before the plugin ends?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Inside a Plugin it is possible to access to the `OutputParameters` only when the step is registered in asynchronous mode or in synchronous mode post-event.

From [MSDN - Understand the Data Context Passed to a Plug-In](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg594416.aspx)

> However, only synchronous post-event and asynchronous registered
>   plug-ins have OutputParameters populated as the response is the result
>   of the core platform operation

Because you registered the step as post-event you can use Daryl's code (the right property is `id` lower case)

From [MSDN - Sample: Basic Plug-In](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309673.aspx#bkmk_inputandoutput)

> Register this plug-in for an account entity, on the Create message,
>   and in asynchronous mode. Alternately, you can register the plug-in on
>   a post-event in the sandbox.

In the basic plugin example there is a warning about the execution mode, because the code uses the `OutputParameters` collection, but it's not explained why.

The code in this example is:

```cs
Guid regardingobjectid = new Guid(context.OutputParameters["id"].ToString());
```

Comment: Has nothing to do with async vs. sync. Daryl's answer is correct, there was just a case error.

Comment: @JoshPainter thanks for spotting the typo. I got confused because I didn't pay attention that the user registered the plugin on post-event. The outputparameters is not populated on synchronous pre-event.

Comment: @JoshPainter I corrected my answer, as you can see (not relevant for the user situation) there is a situation where the execution mode is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are in the Post Creation step of the Invoice, the Guid should be there.

Where are you looking for it?  Have you tried this:

```
Guid id = (Guid)context.OutputParameters["id" ];
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, but this code seems to be giving me a 'key not present' error

Comment: Id must be "id". Case matters! I've edited the answer above.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.createresponse_properties.aspx